# Substitute CHAR(150) in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, char

I have MS Access Table fields which has values **CHAR(150) -** and I like to replace it with **CHAR(45) -**. HOw can I do in MS Access query ?

I tried below in Query but SUBSTITUTE does not exist. It works great in Excel
**Replace(SUBSTITUTE("Value1",CHAR(150),CHAR(45))," ","")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace does substitution. Chr() is Access function.

`Replace([fieldname], Chr(150), Chr(45))`